# Word Automation Service adds file to library - workflow fails to start

Tags: workflow, word-automation

I have a feature which is enabled.  Feature has a library and event receiver.  The library is created when the feature is enabled on a site.  The feature takes files submitted to this library, sends them to the Word Automation Service which then returns a PDF file.

It all works great including a Workflow I have attached to the list which deletes the Word document after 5 minutes because we only want PDF's in this library.

The part that doesn't work is anytime the Word Automation Service sends a file to this library, any workflows fail with an abrupt - Failed on Start.

Errors in the Workflow logs are:

> Workflow [workflow name] was canceled by System Account
>   [workflow name] failed to start

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the PDF file is getting created by System Account.

Workaround is to enable

```
 stsadm -o setproperty -pn declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled -pv true
```

For more information http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start.aspx